# Cannot refresh browser for new version of react app

Tags: reactjs

I try to refresh react app on browser side for new version with this line of javascript :

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

It doesn't work on desktop and android Chrome, which seems to keep displaying the cached version it has.

Comment: reloading the page doesn't reload the cache version of your app. do you have service worker registered in your app?

Comment: no service worker registered

Comment: do you mean the data is cached from the server level or app is not updated to the newer version?

Comment: app is not updated to the newer version